# Pass Request and Response parameters nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a function in services implemented like this

`

@Injectable()
export class AppService
{

getVerifyToken(req:Request,res:Response)
{

try
{

```
        let accessToken=process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_FB;     
        let token =req.query["hub.verify_token"];
        let challange =req.query["hub.challenge"];
        if(challange!=null && token!=null && token==accessToken)
        {
            res.send(challange);
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(400).send();
        }
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        res.status(400).send();
    }
}
```

}
`

I want to pass the Request and Response as a parameter from the controller, however it throws me an error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 6.ts(2554)

`

@Controller()
export class AppController
{
constructor
(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

```
  @Get('/whatsapp')
  verifyToken(){
    return this.appService.getVerifyToken(@Req() req:Request,@Res() res:Response);
  }
```

}
`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `@Req()` and `@Res()` decorators in the route handler of the controller, not in its body. So your code instead should be:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('/whatsapp')
  verifyToken(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response){
    return this.appService.getVerifyToken(req, res);
  }

}
```